# How can I programmatically get a list of open tabs from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, automation

I'm trying to make a tool that encourages me to read/close more tabs on a regular basis.  I am sure that there are ways to do things like this, but I don't know how.  I initially suspected that this might be a flag in the [places database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places) but it looks like it's not.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/List_Open_Tabs). Or if you want to do it externally, look at the session restore files ([located at `<profile>/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js` in current versions](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/06/27/mozilla-launches-improved-session-restore-firefox-33/)), but those aren't always completely up to date - normal delay is 15 seconds.

Comment: Also, I would be interested in seeing such a tool if you ever release it - I tend to have hundreds of tabs open :P

Comment: The tool will end up on github; watch http://github.com/frioux/App-Moirai.  The goal being to motivate me to at least have fewer tabs open today than I had open yesterday.